Why does a pressure difference even create buoyant force?
The derivation of buoyant force seems to be a second step following the understanding of the answer to the present question. Can this be explained in some other way, why would even a pressure difference, whether of a hypothetical liquid column or a real completely immersed object, even create an upthrust?
I analysed it as follows: $F_1 + W = F_2$, giving $F_b = W$, where $F_1$ and $F_2$ are the pressure forces acting on the top and bottom surface, respectively, $F_b$ is buyoancy and $W$ is weight. is this correct? Simply buoyant force balances the weight and is = $A × (P_2 – P_1)$ ?

I like this question: by the time I learned about buoyant force being caused by a differential in the pressure force over the surface of an object, I already had a PhD in nuclear physics from a tip-top school (actually: an Institution, not in Massachusetts).
It's for several reasons, one being it's an integral over a closed surfaces with a vector force dotted into a surface normal and all that, which leaves a resultant force that counteracts a (related) volume integral over density.
But: that is far too general for a PSE answer, so I am going to consider this problem in the simplest form that I can think of. (I am making this up on the spot, so there may be room for improvement).
Suppose we have a column of fluid with density $\rho$. I like Cartesian coordinates, so let's say it has a --no, that has corners. Let's use cylindrical coordinates. This is a cylindrical column of radius R. Let's say the column extends from $z=-H$ to $z=0$.
Of course, we're in a uniform gravitational field $g$.
At any height $-H < z < 0$, the weight of the fluid above is:
$$  W = mg = (\rho V)g = \rho(|z|\pi R^2) g $$
The pressure is the weight per unit area:
$$ p = \frac W A =  \rho g\frac{(|z|\pi R^2)}{\pi R^2} = \rho g |z| $$
The total gravitational potential energy of the fluid is:
$$ U = \int_{z=-H}^0 \rho A g dz = (\pi R^2 \rho g) Z\big|_{-H}^0 = \pi R^2 \rho g H +C = 0 $$
because I choose the integration constant to be:
$$ C = -\pi R^2 \rho g H +C$$
OK, I just realized this whole set up is a mess, since in my mind the buoyant object fills the cylinder.
However, on closer examination of the question, you are talking about neutral buoyancy, which means my set up works.
Now consider a cylindrical mass of radius $R$ and density $\rho$, and height $L$.
If we place it in the cylindrical object on top of the fluid, the total gravitational potential energy becomes:
$$ U = 0 + \frac L 2 \pi R^2 \rho g $$
If move the object up down, say, put the bottom at $z'< -L $, the gravitational potential energy remains unchanged because the density of the fluid is the same as the object.
The force on the object is:
$$ F = -\frac{dU}{dz'} = 0 $$
so it is neutrally buoyant.
If we analyze the pressure forces on the object, then the top has a force:
$$ F_{top} = -(-z'+L)\rho A g $$
$$ F_{bot} = +(-z')\rho A g $$
so the total pressure force is:
$$ F_p = F_{top} + F_{bot} = \big(
-(-z'+L)\rho A g  + (-z')\rho A g
\big)\rho A g =LA\rho g
$$
The gravitational force on the object is:
$$ F_g= -mg =-LA\rho g $$
so that the total force is:
$$ F = F_p + F_g = 0 $$
That's neutral buoyancy.
If you want to consider floating or sinking, then make the fluid's radius $R$ very large compared with the object's radius $R'$.
The pressure calculation remains the same, but the energy calculation changes so that:
$$ F_b = (\rho'-\rho)V g $$


Of course it is the pressure differential which causes the buoyant force. In this picture taken on the international space station, the air bubble stays trapped inside the water because there is no pressure differential above and below the air bubble. It is a basic law that everything in the universe wants to give up energy. So by moving towards the low pressure side in any buoyant situation, the floating object gives up energy. That is it converts potential energy into kinetic energy.
I believe that this is also a description of how gravity works, where things move from a place where time moves faster to a place where time moves slower. In doing so they convert potential energy to kinetic energy.
Exactly like a low pressure system.

"I believe that this is also a description of how gravity works, where things move from a place where time moves faster to a place where time moves slower. " That sounds something like a personal theory.  Is that actually what GR says?  If not, I would remove this part of the post, as the answers here should reflect mainstream physics.

@march it comes to the well accepted concept of hydrostatic equilibrium which is what determines the size of a star. The hot gases of the star creates a pressure that cause it to expand outwards. This is offset by the inward pressure of gravity that holds the star together. When they reach equilibrium you have the size of the star. As the star cools the outward pressure decreases and the star shrinks in size. You note that in both cases the key term is pressure. Thus we have why a pressure system is a better model than the bowling ball in a trampoline.

I guess I'm not really sure why you even mention this in the first place in this answer, since buoyancy is perfectly understandable under very simple models of gravity, i.e., Netwonian gravity. In addition, I think "It is a basic law that everything in the universe wants to give up energy. is much too simplistic to be correct, especially since in this case you'd have to talk about dissipation and possibly entropy maximization at the same type, if you wanted to go that route.  It's much easier, direct, (and likely useful for the OP) to answer this question in terms of Newtonian mechanics.

@march by referring to the ISS air bubble, I was trying to explain that buoyancy is not caused by gravity, other than that gravity creates a pressure differential in the water.  Buoyancy is only caused by this pressure differential, however that might arise.   I probably did get off topic in bringing up the low pressure system as a model for gravity.  It just happened to be on my mind when I wrote the answer.  I never refer to Netwonian gravity - I have an ability to see time under the loop quantum gravity model of GR and it becomes natural for me to bring this into such discussions.
